# Chrome right-click dialog swalllows mouse events

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mouseevent, dom-events

In Chrome the right-click dialog seems to swallow all mouse events. This means that you get mouse-down events without corresponding mouse-up events.

This includes every right-click, and any left-click where the right button is pressed before the left button is released (in which case you get two mouse-downs but no mouse-ups).

You can see the problem in action [here (you may wish to mute your speakers)](http://www2.cs.man.ac.uk/~jackmab1/web-audio/) if you're curious.

I was just wondering if anyone knew of any workarounds for this? Using `window.onmousedown` instead of `document.onmousedown` doesn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to add a handler for the `contextmenu` event that cancels the opening of that menu.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oncontextmenu) for some details.

```
window.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I still have some of the issues that the problem was causing, but I believe that's because my laptop creates middle-button events when you mash left and right mouse buttons.